# How to create a new database in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sqlcmd, database-server

Sorry, if this has been asked previously.
In services on a client, I can see that MS SQL Server has the status "started". and on this machine I don't have Microsoft SQL SERVER Management Studio.

How can I create a new database?

Thank you!

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could always download SSMS Client Tools. Also, just because the service is started, doesn't mean you'll have privileges to create objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use sqlcmd utility and then create script to be executed.

To execute script:
    sqlcmd -i C:\create_script.sql

Db create scritp example:

```
CREATE DATABASE testDb
GO
```

More about the db create options:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities.

You can install MSSQL-Studio on any other pc and connect to your server or you can connect via any sql-client tool and create a database per sql, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms176061.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQLCMD which comes with SQLinstallation..

create a file with create database syntax and save it as .sql file

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

Then use SQLCMD..

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i <MyScript.sql> -o out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With **the MSSQL queries below**, you can create **a database**:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb
GO
```

Then, you can show **all the existed databases**:

```
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
GO
```

> master
> tempdb
> model
> msdb
> testdb

Then, you can drop(delete) **a database**:

```
DROP DATABASE testdb
GO
```